# $(this) except for specific children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to run a function if you click anywhere in an li, except on specific buttons (in which case something else happens). It seems like I should be using either .not or :not, but trying either of the below causes errors and prevents the execution of the function.

Edit: added [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLrdv/2/)
The code follows Blender's advice, by switching live>on and using his syntax, but this has not resolved the problem.

Javascript:

```
$('#currentThread').on('click', 'li:not(.chromeElement)', function () {
    $(this).find('.hiddenChrome').slideToggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='thunderdome'>
    <section id='middle'>
        <ul id='currentThread'>
            <li class="c1L9zObS">
                <article>
                    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ae7238730d03d6da0df35cd8a96ee4dc?d=identicon" class="userPic">
                    <p class="body">foo reply to op</p>
                </article>
                <p class="byline">By <span class="user">raurus</span><span class="timestamp">; Posted a while ago</span><span class="context">2 Tangents</span>
                </p>
                <div class="hiddenChrome" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="chromeElement star">
                        <p>Star</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chromeElement report">
                        <p>Report</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chromeElement delete">
                        <p>Delete</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chromeElement edit">
                        <p>Edit</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chromeElement vote unvoted isLoggedIn"></div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

The goal is that you may click anywhere on the li, it will expand to show you .hiddenChrome

The problem is that clicking a .chromeElement causes the first function to execute and .hiddenChrome to toggle back up. I want to make it so clicking anything /but/ a .chromeElement causes the function to execute.

I do not want to use .slideDown() as toggling is a desired behavior.

Comment: Apart from `.live` being deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9, it does not support chaining! http://api.jquery.com/live/. You get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; ` because you are missing a closing `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on` like this for a more succinct delegation that matches the question

```
$('#currentThread').on('click', 'li:not('.chromeElement)'), function(){ 
    foo();
});
```

However, what you are asking is to stop the event on the parent when the event occurs on a child.  I think you'll need to do two things:

1. if you exclude the child then the event will still fire on the parent item and any "space" which it occupies (including its children) so **put an event handler on the item you want to exclude and exclude it logically** when the event fires
2. use logic to detect which item the event started on and kill the handler.

like this:

```
     $('#currentThread').on('click', 'li, .chromeElement', function (e) {
         var $this = $(this);
         if ($this.closest('.chromeElement').length > 0) {
         // if the click occurs on a chromeElement member then bail
             return false;
         } else {
             $this.find('.hiddenChrome').slideToggle();
         }
     });
```

[your fiddle modified](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/eLrdv/37/)

Answer (score 4):

Your first two examples don't have closing parentheses:

```
$('li').not('.chromeElement').live('click', function(){
  foo
});
 ^


$('li:not(.chromeElement)').live('click', function(){
  foo
});
 ^
```

Also, `.live()` has been removed in jQuery 1.9 and above. Replace it with `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li:not(.chromeElement)', function() {
    foo();
});
```

Change `document` to the selector of the closest non-dynamically-created parent element.